# Is there a simpler way to say whether the current date is within a set range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, boolean, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a fundraising spreadsheet that will say whether funders are currently open or closed for applications. Ideally this would be based on just the month and day, so it doesn't have to be updated every year, but I ran into problems with funding cycles that begin at the end of one year and end in the next (eg. Dec 2020 - Feb 2021). This is what I came up with to get around it, but is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?

It should return Open if today's date falls within the funding window; otherwise it should say Closed. Rolling deadlines are always Open. What I have currently returns the correct output but slows down the sheet. I'm also working with a group of volunteers with varying levels of computer skills and ideally would like to leave them with something that is easy to understand/maintain.

Here is a link to the demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lHFd0f_y2PCzLSvXYM6XD1rCfdzCglsQvyfpu7xJiRQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
   =IF(B77="rolling","Open",IF(YEAR(B77)=YEAR(C77),
   IF(
      AND(
         DATE(YEAR(B77),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))>=B77,
         DATE(YEAR(C77),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))<=C77),
      "Open",
      "Closed"),
   IF(
      OR(
         DATE(YEAR(B77),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))>=B77,
         DATE(YEAR(C77),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))<=C77),
      "Open",
      "Closed")))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Aside from providing a sample sheet. Please include your expected output. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: I've added a test sheet and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet.

I deleted your header and all of your row-by-row formulas from Column C and replaced them with the following single array formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Status Today"; IF(A2:A="",,IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),"Open",IF((TODAY()>=A2:A)*(TODAY()<=B2:B),"Open","Closed")))})`

This one formula will produce the header (which you can change as you like within the formula itself) and all column results.

First, an `IF` test is run to see if each cell in Column A is blank. If it is, then the corresponding cell in Column C is left null; otherwise the next `IF` test is initiated.

Since all of your dates are numbers, the second `IF` test simply checks to see if the value in Column A `ISTEXT`. If so, then we know it is "rolling," and the return value is "Open"; if not, then the final `IF` test is initiated.

The final `IF` test simply checks whether two parenthetical conditions are true (joined by the asterisk, which in array formulas, means `AND`). The two conditions are that `TODAY()` is greater-than-or-equal-to the value in Column A and that `TODAY()` is less-than-or-equal-to the value in Column B. If so, "Open" is returned; otherwise, "Closed" is returned.